# How to get months between 2 given months

Tags: mysql, date, calendar

Hey guys I want to get a month list which contain the months between 2 given month. For ex if i give month from January to June. Then I should be able to get all the months between them. I want to use those months in a repeater header. Can you tell me the query

```
select month(str_to_date('January','%M')); -- 1
select month(str_to_date('June','%M')); -- 6
```

Through the above code I will get the month numbers now i want to get the months between these 2.

Comment: Why would you use SQL for this? Just do it in code instead and loop from 2 to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give several rows, each with a month number between those months then you can do something like this:-

```
SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('January','%M')) + Sub1.aMonth
FROM (SELECT 0 AS aMonth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) Sub1
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('January','%M')) + Sub1.aMonth <= MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('June','%M'))
```

That is assuming the months are in the same year

To give you the month names probably easiest to add the month number as the number of months to a starting date (in this case 1st Jan 2013) and then use MONTHNAME:-

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD('2013-01-01', INTERVAL Sub1.aMonth MONTH))
FROM (SELECT 0 AS aMonth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) Sub1
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('January','%M')) + Sub1.aMonth <= MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('June','%M'))
```

Comment: Hey man your code works, but can I get month names as output instead of month numbers ?

Comment: Added a suggestion for that.

Comment: Hey man would it be possible if I get month names as abbreviations and not complete names of months ? Actually am using 2 repeaters and due to the uneven names of some months they formatting is not acceptable.

Comment: Instead of using MONTHNAME you could use DATE_FORMAT, using a format of '%b'

Answer (score 0):

You could try using select (what you want) from table where (var_first_month) between (second_month). hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT  month(str_to_date(`your_date_column`,'%M')) as my_month
   FROM `your_table`
   WHERE month(str_to_date(`your_date_column`,'%M')) BETWEEN month(str_to_date('January','%M')) 
                            AND   month(str_to_date('June','%M'))
```

Comment: Hey I have Month names in my table not the numbers. And i want month names as output. You query looks fine but can you change it so that I get the month names from table.

Answer (score 0):

If months are in the same year, I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(months.m, '%m'), '%M')
FROM
  (SELECT 1 m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
   UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
   UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months
WHERE
  months.m > month(str_to_date('January','%M'))
  AND months.m < month(str_to_date('June','%M'));
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/15461). But depending on the situation, it might be easier to get month names by code (e.g. using PHP or another script...)